# Date module in Drupal accepting 00 for Date and Month values

Tags: php, drupal, date, datepicker

I have a form that accepts date from user. I used the Drupal Date popup module and i am able to select dates using that
 popup. But this date control is also editable. i.e. i can also enter the dates manually.
 I fixed an issue of older dates being selected for the control (it was a client requirement) i used strtotime for that.
 Now due to the fact that values can be entered manually, the dates like 00/23/2012 (where mm/dd/yyyy is expected) can be added in the text box and
 it gets deciphered as 12/23/2012.

[This is the UI for the same](http://imageshack.us/f/100/timemanual.jpg/)
 The 00 is accepted for dates as well/
 What can be done to prevent it from taking 00 as value for date and month during manual entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `hook_form_validate()` to check the value if its  not as per your requirement then throw and error.